# I need to turn an array of arrays into an array of cbtItem using TypeScript and Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, interface

I need to turn an array of arrays into an array of cbtItem using TypeScript and Angular. ctbItem is an interface

This is the code of the publicatorservice.service.ts:

```
turnarray( data: any [][] ){
const dataobj: cbtItem[]= data.map(function(row){
      return {
        a: row[0],
        b: row[1],
        c: row[2],
        d: row[3],
        e: row[4],
        f: row[5],
        g: row[6],
        h: row[7],
      }
    });
    
    this.ELEMENT_DATA = dataobj;

    console.log(this.ELEMENT_DATA);
  }
```

This is the code of the interface.ts:

```
export interface cbtItem  {
    listing_type_id:                  string;
    title:                            string;
    available_quantity:               number;
    category_id:                      string;
    buying_mode:                      string;
    currency_id:                      string;
    condition:                        string;
    site_id:                          string;
    price:                            number;
    accepts_mercadopago:              boolean;
    non_mercado_pago_payment_methods: any[];
    warranty:                         string;
    sale_terms:                       SaleTerm[];
    attributes:                       Attribute[];
    pictures:                         Picture[];
    description:                      Description;
}

export interface Attribute {
    id:                    string;
    value_name:            string;
    name?:                 string;
    value_id?:             null | string;
    value_struct?:         null;
    values?:               Value[];
    attribute_group_id?:   string;
    attribute_group_name?: string;
    source?:               number;
}

export interface Value {
    id:     null | string;
    name:   string;
    struct: null;
    source: number;
}

export interface Description {
    plain_text: string;
}

export interface Picture {
    source: string;
}

export interface SaleTerm {
    id:          string;
    value_name?: string;
    value_id?:   string;
}
```

I am getting this error:

"
Type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string; d: string; e: string; f: string; g: string; h: string; i: string; j: string; k: string; l: string; m: string; n: string; o: string; p: string; q: string; r: string; s: string; t: string; u: string; ... 18 more ...; an: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'cbtItem[]'
"

Hope you can help me, thank you

Comment: Please cut this down to a [mre]. What's `data`? If it's an array of arrays *of strings* as the error suggests, how *are* you planning to get those non-string values?

Comment: ```turnarray( data: string [][] ){

    const dataobj: cbtItem []= data.map(function(row){
      return {
        a: row[0],
        b: row[1],
        c: row[2],
        d: row[3],
        e: row[4],
 
      }
    });
    
    this.ELEMENT_DATA = dataobj;

    console.log(this.ELEMENT_DATA);


    

  }```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of the code, I am trying to fix it changing the type of the array of arrays to any and I am getting the same error

Comment: [Edit] the question, we probably don't need even five props for the example.

Comment: But like this: Type '{ a: any; b: any; c: any; d: any; e: any; f: any; g: any; h: any; i: any; j: any; k: any; l: any; m: any; n: any; o: any; p: any; q: any; r: any; s: any; t: any; u: any; v: any; w: any; x: any; y: any; z: any; aa: any; ab: any; ac: any; ad: any; ae: any; af: any; ... 7 more ...; an: any; }[]' is not assignable to type 'cbtItem[]'

Comment: Ok, I already edited the question

Comment: Please try again. `any[][]` tells us (and the compiler, for that matter, so it's no surprise it's not happy) next to nothing about what you're actually dealing with. Read [mre] carefully and give the information needed to recreate this issue elsewhere.

Comment: Property names do not match. In the object you create from row, use property names from cbtitem.

Comment: Thanks, you were right, I did what you said and there is no error.

Comment: Can I ask you other question? I have others sub-interfaces, you can see them in interface.ts, I am trying to add these sub-interfaces to the turnarray function, but I don't know how to do that